# Can ESP8266 be hacked?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, wifi

I have a ESP8266 linked to my home wifi. Is it possible for someone from outside to have access to it and further is it possible to hack into my network? If yes how do I protect it ?

Comment: Did you write hackable code on it?

Comment: As far as I know everything in this world is hackable. So you should rather be worried on how hard it is to hack.

Comment: Or rather - how bad the things would be if it gets hacked. And why would anyone want to hack it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems it's already hacked - [link here](https://hackaday.com/2019/09/05/esp8266-and-esp32-wifi-hacked/).

Even if they say these hacks are fixed on newer devices, who knows when the next vulnerability is found.

Has someone prove that it is unhackable? If not so you must assume it is hackable, right?

Comment: I'd also add that same applies for other home WiFi devices. I.e. router itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you don't rely on a single mechanism to ensure the security of your network. Even if there'd be no currently known exploits, there might be one in the future if an attacker is sufficiently motivated.

Consider what would happen if someone was to compromise a part of your network such as an ESP8266 and try to have additional measures in place so that the compromise can't easily be escalated further.

In your specific example having some firewall rules that restrict what the ESP8266 can do might be helpful. E.g. you could restrict it to not have internet access to hopefully prevent data exfiltration, restrict which hosts on the local network it can communicate with to make it harder to compromise additional machines on the network, restrict which protocols it's allowed to speak with that limited set of hosts, and so on.

Comment: do you know what is esp8266?